# How to Export Enabled Simple products sku with mysql query in magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database

I want to export enabled simple products SKU from magento admin export function is not working fine.  I have tried to export many times, and it's showing too many extra records.  Now i want to try exporting from a MySQL query.  I will need the results in the form of a CSV file.

Get Parent Config and Child Associated SKU's List.

Answer (score 0):

Put this file in your magento root folder.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<?php 
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
set_time_limit(0);
$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
      ->addFieldToFilter('status',array(1));
$count =0;
$attr_array=array();
?>
<table border="2" id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>SKU</td>
</tr>
<?php
    foreach($products as $pro){
   ?>
   <tr><td><?php echo $pro['sku'] ?></td></tr>
   <?php
   }
?>
</table>
 <a href="#" id="test" onClick="javascript:fnExcelReport();">download</a>
 <script>
function fnExcelReport() {
var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';

tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';

tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
tab_text = tab_text + $('#myTable').html();
tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
            type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
        });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'all_skus.xls');
    }
} else {
    $('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'all_skus.xls');
}
}
</script>
```

And then run the file,for example

yourdomain.com/file_name.php

And click the download below the result,you will get result in csv file.

Comment: let me know,if this is your solution.